# PySpark - MERGE INTO TABLE is not supported temporarily

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently trying to merge two tables in a fresh virtual environment with only pyspark and pyspark[sql] installed. I have created views for each of the tables and run some basic queries which run fine. But the following query using Merge fails-

```
MERGE INTO current
USING (

SELECT updates.Name as mergeKey, updates.*
FROM updates

UNION ALL
    
SELECT NULL as mergeKey, updates.*
FROM updates JOIN current
ON updates.Name = current.Name 
WHERE current.current = true 

) staged_updates
ON current.Name = mergeKey
WHEN MATCHED AND current.current = true THEN  
    UPDATE SET current = false, validity_end = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()    
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT(S_No,Name, DOB, validity_start, validity_end, current) 
    VALUES(null,staged_updates.Name, staged_updates.updated_DOB, current_timestamp(), null, true)
```

I get the following error when I run  the query using `spark.sql(merge_query)`-

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkUnsupportedOperationException: MERGE INTO TABLE is not supported temporarily.
```

The complete error code can be found here - https://pastebin.com/mgL92Vgx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with only pyspark and pyspark[sql] installed

Merge or updates/delete are not implemented in vanilla spark. You will need to add a dependency such:

- apache hudi
- apache iceberg
- delta lake